# How to log Google Analytics calls in Testcafe?

Tags: testing, google-analytics, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am trying to automatically test tracking code and I am using [the RequestLogger from Testcafé](http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/logging-http-requests.html). I succeeded to intercept calls to `example.com` and `localhost` but not to `https://www.google-analytics.com/`. What could be the reason?

## Expected

### This test should be green

#### Test code

```
import { RequestLogger } from 'testcafe';
const logger_ga = RequestLogger('https://www.google-analytics.com/');

fixture `localhost`
 .page('http://localhost:8000')

test  
   .requestHooks(logger_ga)
     ('logs calls to Google Analytics', async t => {
       await t.click("#ga-button");
       console.log(logger_ga.requests); // is empty due to timing
       await t.expect(logger_ga.contains(record => record.response.statusCode === 200)).ok();
});
```

#### Fixture for this test

I am serving the following `index.html` page via `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Hello world!</p>

  <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-Y to be your site's ID. -->
  <script>
    window.ga = function () { ga.q.push(arguments) }; ga.q = []; ga.l = +new Date;
    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto'); ga('send', 'pageview')
  </script>
  <script src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js" async defer></script>

  <a onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'my_event_category', 'my_event_action', 'my_event_label');" href="#" id="ga-button">Google Analytics</a>
</body>

</html>
```

## Observed

### The above test is red

[image: Google Analytics call interception is red]

### However, these tests are green

```
import { RequestLogger } from 'testcafe';

const logger = RequestLogger('http://example.com');

fixture `example`
    .page('http://example.com');

test
    .requestHooks(logger)
    ('logs calls to example.com', async t => {
      await t.expect(logger.contains(record => record.response.statusCode === 200)).ok(); // green
});


const logger_localhost = RequestLogger('http://localhost:8000');

fixture `localhost`
    .page('http://localhost:8000');

test
    .requestHooks(logger_localhost)
    ('logs calls to localhost', async t => {
      await t.expect(logger_localhost.contains(record => record.response.statusCode === 200)).ok(); // green
});
```

How can I intercept calls to Google Analytics successfully?

Comment: It is possible that the issue is related to TestCafe timeouts: t.expect waits for 3 seconds and this time might be not enough to load a resource. Try calling "wait" before "expect": await t.wait(4000).expect(logger.contains(record => record.response.statusCode === 200)).ok();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Marion suggested it is probably due to timing. The following code works:

```
import { Selector, RequestLogger } from 'testcafe';

const gaCollect = 'https://www.google-analytics.com/collect';

const gaLogger = RequestLogger({gaCollect}, {
  logRequestHeaders:     true,
  logRequestBody:        true,
});


fixture `Fixture`
    .page('http://localhost:8000')
    .requestHooks(gaLogger);

test('Log Google Analytics call', async t => {
    await t.click('#ga-button')

    await t.expect(gaLogger.contains(record =>
      record.request.url.match(/ec=my_event_category&ea=my_event_action&el=my_event_label/))).ok();

    for(let r of gaLogger.requests) {
      console.log("*** logger url: ", r.request.url);
    }

});
```

[image]

The timing factor @Marion mentioned seems to play a role. Compare the previous with the following snippet and its output. Here, we do not see the calls logged to https://google-analytics.com/collect.

```
fixture `Fixture`
    .page('http://localhost:8000')
    .requestHooks(gaLogger);

test('Log Google Analytics call', async t => {
    await t.click('#ga-button')

    for(let r of gaLogger.requests) {
      console.log("*** logger url: ", r.request.url);
    }

    await t.expect(gaLogger.contains(record =>
      record.request.url.match(/ec=my_event_category&ea=my_event_action&el=my_event_label/))).ok();
});
```

[image]